# Changing an observation

Tags: r, left-join, rename

I used left_join to merge two dataframes using a "country name" variable in R. Some observations are now showing as n/a because the spelling for a country (eg. Congo, DR.) is different in the other dataset (eg. Democratic Republic of the Congo). What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Please use `dput()` to provide an example of your two data sets in order to help. Is there some other key than the country name to set a link between the two data frames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change all entries in a dataframe `df` with something like this, then combine them.

`df[df == "Congo, DR"] <- "Democratic Republic of the Congo"`

It does mean you have to find them all and do it "manually" for everyone though.